# KeyError with plotting cluster centers

Tags: python, cluster-computing, center

ax = df_seeds_train[df_seeds_train['cluster']==0].plot(kind='scatter', x='asymmetry', y='perimeter', s=50, c='green', sharex=False)
    df_seeds_train[df_seeds_train['cluster']==1].plot(kind='scatter',x='asymmetry',y='perimeter',s=50, c='orange', sharex=False, ax = ax)
    df_seeds_train[df_seeds_train['cluster']==2].plot(kind='scatter',x='asymmetry',y='perimeter',s=50, c='purple', sharex=False, ax = ax)

```
centers.plot(kind = 'scatter', x='asymmetry', y='perimeter', c='red', s=50, marker='x', sharex=False, ax=ax)
```

I need to get red markers in the center of my clusters but I keep getting KeyErrors for 'asymmetry' and 'perimeteter'. Does anybody know how to fix this. I added an image of the outcome I get now.[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIt3r.png)

Thanks in advance!
[df_seeds_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xejIJ.png)

Comment: can you provide a minimal example so we can better understand your problem? how is it structured your `df_seeds_train`?

Comment: `df_seeds_train = df_seeds.copy()

km_seeds = KMeans(n_clusters=3)

km_seeds.fit(df_seeds_train)

center_seeds = pd.DataFrame(km_seeds.cluster_centers_, columns=df_seeds_train.columns)

df_seeds_train['cluster'] = km_seeds.labels_`

Comment: can you print the first few rows of your df?

Comment: I added a image of the first rows of the df